# How to pull a key from a dict (pandas series) to its own row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

Here is my example data with two fields where the last one [outbreak] is a pandas series.

Start:
[image: Start]

Goal (Excel mock-up):
[image: Goal]

Reproduction Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

d = {'report_id': [100, 101], 'outbreak': [
    '{"outbreak_100":{"name":"Chris","disease":"A-Pox"},"outbreak_101":{"name":"Stacy","disease": "H-Pox"}}', 
    '{"outbreak_200":{"name":"Brandon","disease":"C-Pox"},"outbreak_201":{"name":"Karen","disease": "G-Pox"},"outbreak_202":{"name":"Tim","disease": "Z-Pox"}}']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(type(df['outbreak']))
display(df)

#Ignore
df = pd.json_normalize(df['outbreak'].apply(json.loads), max_level=0)
display(df)
```

Attempts:
I thought about using json_normalize() which would convert every [outbreak_id] to its own field and then use pandas.wide_to_long() to get my final output. It works in testing but my concern is that my actual production data is **so long and nested** that it ends up generating hundred of thousands of fields before pivoting. That does not sounds good to me and why I also hope to avoid loop iterations.

I also thought about using df = df.explode('outbreak') but I am getting a KeyError: 0

Perhaps someone has a better idea than I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import json
d = {'report_id': [100, 101], 'outbreak': [
    '{"outbreak_100":{"name":"Chris","disease":"A-Pox"},"outbreak_101":{"name":"Stacy","disease": "H-Pox"}}', 
    '{"outbreak_200":{"name":"Brandon","disease":"C-Pox"},"outbreak_201":{"name":"Karen","disease": "G-Pox"},"outbreak_202":{"name":"Tim","disease": "Z-Pox"}}']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# use json.loads to parse the json and construct df from it
df = pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('report_id')['outbreak'].map(json.loads).to_dict()).stack().rename_axis(['outbreak_id', 'report_id'], axis=0).reset_index(name='outbreak_value')
print(df)
    outbreak_id  report_id                           outbreak_value
0  outbreak_100        100    {'name': 'Chris', 'disease': 'A-Pox'}
1  outbreak_101        100    {'name': 'Stacy', 'disease': 'H-Pox'}
2  outbreak_200        101  {'name': 'Brandon', 'disease': 'C-Pox'}
3  outbreak_201        101    {'name': 'Karen', 'disease': 'G-Pox'}
4  outbreak_202        101      {'name': 'Tim', 'disease': 'Z-Pox'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `ast` convert to `dict` format , then we do conversion

```
import ast 
out = df.pop('outbreak').map(ast.literal_eval).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1).join(df)
out.columns = ['outbreak_id','outbreak_value','report_id']
Out[157]: 
        level_1                                        0  report_id
0  outbreak_100    {'name': 'Chris', 'disease': 'A-Pox'}        100
0  outbreak_101    {'name': 'Stacy', 'disease': 'H-Pox'}        100
1  outbreak_200  {'name': 'Brandon', 'disease': 'C-Pox'}        101
1  outbreak_201    {'name': 'Karen', 'disease': 'G-Pox'}        101
1  outbreak_202      {'name': 'Tim', 'disease': 'Z-Pox'}        101
```

Comment: Hi Beny, everything in your post I somewhat understood except for this portion right here: ".map(ast.literal_eval)", can you clarify what you're doing here? Google brought up abstract syntax trees and I got lost pretty quickly. Think it's possible for you to explain in simple terms for a simple person like me?

Comment: @Anonymous this is to convert the string back to object which is dict ~

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to convert the json for each outbreak into a dictionary, make a list of all the dictionary key/value pairs and then explode that list and convert the values into the two desired columns:

```py
df['outbreak'] = df['outbreak'].apply(lambda v:json.loads(v).items())
df = df.explode('outbreak')
df[['outbreak_id', 'outbreak_value']] = pd.DataFrame(df.pop('outbreak').tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
   report_id   outbreak_id                           outbreak_value
0        100  outbreak_100    {'name': 'Chris', 'disease': 'A-Pox'}
0        100  outbreak_101    {'name': 'Stacy', 'disease': 'H-Pox'}
1        101  outbreak_200  {'name': 'Brandon', 'disease': 'C-Pox'}
1        101  outbreak_201    {'name': 'Karen', 'disease': 'G-Pox'}
1        101  outbreak_202      {'name': 'Tim', 'disease': 'Z-Pox'}
```

Note: if the `outbreak` values are already `dicts`, not `JSON`, change the first line of this code to:

```
df['outbreak'] = df['outbreak'].apply(dict.items)
```

Comment: I was reviewing and testing your answer and was just going to ask you what to do if it's already a dict and you beat me to the punch! I wish I could give everyone selected answer. Thank you for help again!

Comment: @Anonymous I saw your comment to notarobot so I got ahead of the game :) You should always accept the answer which is best for your needs, so no worries about that. I think it's great you got 3 different ways of doing it.